# How to put APNS callback in something other than AppDelegate?

Tags: objective-c, cordova, apple-push-notifications

I have a requirement to align the user's login for my PhoneGap iOS app with the deviceToken that is returned from APNS.  I'm using PhoneGap to build out this functionality so I thought of writing a plugin that will kick off the need for APNS after the login page and then save that on our servers with the username I get from login.

So far I have that piece working but when the "didFinishLaunchingWithOptions" callback is initiated it goes back to the AppDelegate class (the PhoneGap bootstrap class) and the user's ID isn't in that class so I have a property set so that the plugin class can use it.  My question is there anyway I can keep this callback in my plugin class so it will have a handle to the userId? Are there other ways to deal with this which seems to me a common use case?

This is the (partial) code for my PhoneGap plugin:

```
    @implementation ApplePushNotificationService

    - (void)registerDevice:(CDVInvokedUrlCommand *)command {
        [self.commandDelegate runInBackground:^{
            uid = [command.arguments objectAtIndex:0];
            version = [self osVersionBuild];
            pluginResult = nil;

            // Register device for push notifications
            [[UIApplication sharedApplication] registerForRemoteNotificationTypes:(UIRemoteNotificationTypeAlert |
                                                                               UIRemoteNotificationTypeBadge |
                                                                               UIRemoteNotificationTypeSound)];
            [self processToken];

            // return result
            [self.commandDelegate sendPluginResult:pluginResult callbackId:command.callbackId];
        }];
    }
    - (void) processToken
{
    // Get UID from calling class
    NSString* deviceToken = ((AppDelegate*)[[UIApplication sharedApplication] delegate]).token;

    NSMutableURLRequest *request = [NSMutableURLRequest requestWithURL:[NSURL URLWithString:@"https://xxx/app/apns/register/"]];
    [request setHTTPMethod:@"POST"];
    [request setValue:@"application/json; charset=utf-8" forHTTPHeaderField:@"Content-Type"];

    // Create JSON to POST
    NSDictionary *json = [[NSDictionary alloc] initWithObjectsAndKeys:
                          [NSString stringWithString:uid], @"uid",
                          @"ios", @"type",
                          [NSString stringWithString:deviceToken], @"registrationId",
                          @"0.0.2", @"version",
                          nil];
    NSError *error = nil;
    NSData* jsonData = [NSJSONSerialization dataWithJSONObject:json options:NSJSONWritingPrettyPrinted error:&error];

    if (jsonData) {
        request.HTTPBody = jsonData;

        // Create url connection and fire request
        NSURLConnection *conn = [[NSURLConnection alloc] initWithRequest:request delegate:self];
    } else {
        NSLog(@"Unable to serialize the data %@: %@", json, error);
    }
}
```

Notice the uid is set from an incoming argument and here's the code for the callback:

```
@synthesize token; // defined in .h as @property (nonatomic, readwrite) NSString* token;    
- (void) application:(UIApplication *)application didRegisterForRemoteNotificationsWithDeviceToken:(NSData *)deviceToken
    {
        NSLog( @"Device token is: %@", deviceToken);
        // Convert to string that can be stored in DB
        NSString *regId = [[deviceToken description] stringByReplacingOccurrencesOfString:@"<" withString:@""];
        regId = [regId stringByReplacingOccurrencesOfString:@">" withString:@""];
        regId = [regId stringByReplacingOccurrencesOfString: @" " withString: @""];

        self.token = regId;
    }
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You cannot change this functionality so when the device receive APNS callback the method in App delegate will be fired to handle that.

You can create singleton class of your ApplePushNotificationService and add new method to handle incoming events. After that just call it in your app delegate. For example:

```
// AppDelegate.m

- (void) application:(UIApplication *)application didRegisterForRemoteNotificationsWithDeviceToken:(NSData *)deviceToken
{
    [[ApplePushNotificationService sharedInstance] application:application didRegisterForRemoteNotificationsWithDeviceToken: deviceToken];
}
```

Of course it require to add new method do ApplePushNotificationService class `application: didRegisterForRemoteNotificationsWithDeviceToken:` and create new singleton `sharedInstance`, as follows:

```
// ApplePushNotificationService.h
+ (void) application:(UIApplication *)application uploadDeviceToken:(NSString *)deviceToken;

// ApplePushNotificationService.m
+ (ApplePushNotificationService *)sharedInstance
{
    // ...
}
+ (void) application:(UIApplication *)application uploadDeviceToken:(NSString *)deviceToken
{
    //...
}
```

Hope this help

Comment: Ok, I was going down this road yesterday, but after adding the code above (added to your answer with the singleton), I get `No visible @interface for 'ApplePushNotificationService' declares the selector 'application:uploadDeviceToken'`. But indeed I have done that, so my question is how to I make it visible to the calling method in AppDelegate?

Comment: I guess you added method application:uploadDeviceToken to .m file, right? You need to add method declaration to .h file as well.

Comment: Yes, correct. See my addendum to your answer for details. The declaration is in .h and implementation in .m.

Comment: I think I got it now.  I had the method as static (+) so it wasn't visible to AppDelegate.

Comment: If you wouldn't mind accepting my edits to your answer to include the singleton, I'll accept this as the answer. Thanks so much!

Comment: I couldn't approve it because too much people rejected your suggestion (because to much integration in original content). I added it as post extension.

Comment: That's fine the only thing is that the + should - for the updateDeviceToken method.